# how to run ffmpeg commands from browser

Tags: javascript, android, ffmpeg

I have been able to stream live camera feed from my laptop camera to an adobe media server. I am running the commands in command prompt in my laptop. I wanted to know how to connect this to a browser where I can run these commands from a web browser. I mean access the camera from the browser and run the ffmpeg commands to stream the camera feed to the rtmp server.

Comment: You can setup a server (NodeJS, Apache?) on the machine that will do the work. You can then send commands from your page (Ajax requests?) to that server, which will execute them on the system it is running on. But your question is a bit too broad for this site. There are many possible answers.

Comment: Thanks. Just how we attach nodejs scripts to ports and run it from the browser, can we do the same thing with ffmpeg as well? I have a php server and I can install ffmpeg there but from what I have read I have found that the php ffmpeg library is outdated. How do apps like periscope and meerkat stream it?

Comment: If you're using NodeJS, you can run commands just like you would in your Linux shell. So if, for example, your server is on linux, you could run commands to control ffmpeg directly on the system. Check this out: https://dzone.com/articles/execute-unix-command-nodejs

Comment: Ok. But I am using php. My site is based on php and it streams live events. Currently I am using Open Broadcaster software to stream it to my adobe server. But I am working on ffmpeg to develop my own encoding software so that even others can stream to my server from their web browser